Facebook login for Business app type is not working
I have created a Business type app on Facebook Developer portal and configured my iOS app with App ID and client token. When user tries to login it shows error "It looks like this app isn't available". I have verified my business on Facebook Developer portal and have advance access to public_profile and email permissions.
Permissions added in login request: public_profile, email
There are two APIs for login, I tried with both as shown below but got same error
LoginManager().logIn(configuration: config, completion: { result in
// handle result
}

LoginManager().logIn(permissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: nil, handler: { result, error in
// handle result and error
}

Could someone please let me know what is the cause of this issue and what is the solution for this?
